# The "L" tag on SO

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, tags, tag-creation

It seems it's possible to enter a tag with just the single letter [l](/questions/tagged/l) and post a question as such. Does this [l](/questions/tagged/l) tag have any significance ?

See for example: [Mapping groups of constant values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222633/mapping-groups-of-constant-values)

Comment: Yep - it has a [significance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_(Death_Note))... just wait until I find an excuse to add the Kira tag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure you can - the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag is very common on Stack Overflow for example.

One of the "risks" in having high reputation is creating tags by mistake - so it's our responsibility as high rep members to overview our questions after posting them and correct such mistakes.

Removing the tag from the question will make it disappear after a day or so assuming no other question was tagged with it during this time, so no harm done.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can create a tag with a single letter, tag [c](/questions/tagged/c) ,[r](/questions/tagged/r) and [d](/questions/tagged/d) also has one letter. [Creating a tag requires 1500 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags). In your case I assume that it happened because you were in hurry to post a question. You just hit the 'Enter Key' after the tag [constants](/questions/tagged/constants) and during that time a key of 'l' has been pressed. Now you have reputation of 3K on Stack Overflow so system has created a new tag [l](/questions/tagged/l)