# New tag should require more privilege

Tags: feature-request, tags

I am a relatively new user in Ask Ubuntu site, which is a subsite of the Stack Exchange network. After participating in the Questions and answers in the AU site for a while, I see that, the "tags" are very important in this site. *(It is also very important on all SE sites)*. I often see and feel that, Moderators and Community members have a hard time deleting tags, which were created by users *(without having good knowledge about the importance of tags*). I also experienced a situation where a user trying to delete [ubuntu-netbook](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-netbook) tag, created a new one as [ubuntu-n](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-n) accidentally and was unaware of this new tag. *(We are requested to delete that tag, because that is no longer important)*.

So, I feel that, tag creation should not be that easy and should go through some approval by moderators before being used in the system. That's why I am proposing this request.

We can apply to the system one or more of these methods to prevent unimportant tags being created.

- We can increase the required reputation level from 300 to 2000. It is [now](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/create-tags) 300
- New tags should go through moderator approval before being used. The user can still type a new tag name, but that new tag will only appear in the question after moderator approval

I want to hear from community members about this particular request.

Comment: read both the [answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137824/173001) you will get your answer :)

Comment: Which site are you talking about? Creating tags requires 500 here on meta.so, as you point out, but [only 300 on ask ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/create-tags), and [1500 on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags)...

Comment: sorry, I was asking about AU. edited the question

Comment: You need to talk about raising that bar on meta.askubuntu.com, then, as it's a site-specific setting. 300 rep *does* sound low for the "create tag" privilege. But as far as making moderators approve new tags: ugh.

Comment: With reputation comes responsibility - it's as simple as that.

Comment: I don't think more privilege is the answer. But a [confirmation pop-up to make creating tags a little more annoying and avoid it happening by mistake](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62591/warning-or-confirmation-on-new-tag-creation) would be nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

300 is quite a high enough limit honestly. I mean, if you reach 300 rep, it means you did participate in the community and the site itself (at least a bit).
2K seems like too much for me. Tags are important — yes — but a wrong tag might not create so many problems, and in any case, not that many problems to justify a 2K limit privilege.

Another thing: apart from the fact that moderators already have quite a few duties to take care of, adding this one wouldn't have that much effect. Consider that a tag, in order to survive, **must be used**.

If you create a tag and nobody else uses it, the system will purge it. So it's not like a wrong tag is a scar forever. It'll be seen sooner or later, either by the **system** or by the **community**: no need for exclusive moderator action.